# Xaml Emoticons values not displaying when running

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, emoticons

Am working on Universal Windows application and am reading string and if the string contains smiley characters (For eg. **😕**) its not getting displayed.

But when I try to declare it statically, Like

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x1F60A;" />
```

Am getting the smiley in my emulator, also when my emulator is running. But when I try to work this out via C#, am getting the value as it is. I can't see the smiley here. Like this,

```
textBlock.Text = "&#x1F60A;";
```

Do I need to change any textblock properties so that I may get the smileys?

Comment: What happens with "\ud83d\ude0a"? (Do note that "&#x1F60A;" is html-escaped, it has nothing to do with .NET)

Comment: @flindeberg Thanks a lot buddy. But where can I get that code for all the smileys? Am working on that, and am reading all smileys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to have a look at http://www.charbase.com/block/emoticons which provides a good overview of emoticons in unicode. Java and .NET seem to use the same escape mechanisms.

In the case of your smiley `\ud83d\ude0a` would probably do the trick. Your original format `&#x1F60A;` is html-escaped, not .NET escaped.